# Select query to get values from a table column only if the values are not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please somebody suggest me with a SQL Server Select query to get values from a table column if only the values are not in another table, this is what I want to do:

```
SELECT t.TeacherID
FROM Teacher t ...... (Who are not in Class c, c.TeacherID Column)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select teacherID from Teacher
Except
select teacherID from Class
```

or you can also go for:

```
select teacherID from Teacher where TeacherId not in(select teacherID from Class)
```

Comment: +1 This Works..!! Thanks Sonam, Im gonna go with your first answer

Answer (score 1):

Teachers who ***do not*** have classes:

```
SELECT *
FROM   teacher
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   class
         WHERE  class.teacherid = teacher.teacherid
       )
```

If you want to do the inverse (find teachers who ***do*** have classes) then all you have to do is reverse the condition: remove the `NOT`!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a LEFT JOIN WHERE no teacher iD is assigned a class

```
`SELECT teacher.ID `
`FROM   teacher LEFT JOIN Class ON teacher.ID =  Class.ID`
`WHERE   Class.ID IS NOT NULL`
```